# Fluent NHibernate Many To Many on Same Table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How can I create relation like this?

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UserId);
        Map(x => x.UserName);
        Map(x => x.Password);
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.FBFriends).Cascade.All().Table("UserFBFriend");
        HasManyToMany(x => x.FBFriends).Cascade.All().Inverse().Table("UserFBFriend");
    }
}

public class User : BaseClass<User>
{
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<User> FBFriends { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        FBFriends = new List<User>();
    }

    public virtual void AddUserFBFriend(User user)
    {
        user.FBFriends.Add(this);
        FBFriends.Add(user);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
    HasManyToMany(x => x.LeftFBFriends).Cascade.All().Table("UserFBFriend");
    HasManyToMany(x => x.RightFBFriends).Cascade.All().Inverse().Table("UserFBFriend");

    public virtual IList<User> LeftFBFriends { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<User> RightFBFriends { get; set; }
    public User()
    {
        LeftFBFriends = new List<User>();
        RightFBFriends = new List<User>();
    }
```

Comment: This won't work. The relation must be expressed by **two** collections. E.g.  `IList<User> LeftFBFriends { get; set; }` - `IList<User> RightFBFriends { get; set; }`. So you can be friend with someone - then you will be stored in the left column of the pairing table. Or you are tracked as friend of someone - the right col of pair is used. Maybe weird. But that's in fact many-to-many on self

Comment: yeah Its wierd. any alternative?

Comment: NO NO. Collection will be different. The best is to think about it, like they are not the same... because one collection is representing relation based on left column - the other on the right column. Does it help?

Comment: I would say, there is no real alternative. Just these two collections. The issue is, that if you will be someones friend - he can be also your friend - I mean two records/rows in pairing table. A - B and B - A. Some business logic around... it will work. but it is ... challenging

Comment: @RadimKöhler I made changes like UPDATE now It gives me error of "Could not determine type for: Entity.User, Entity, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(User)" did I understand your guidance wrong?

Comment: NHibernate needs to know, which column to use for which collection (which will use column A, which column B)... so we have to be explicit here. Give me sec.. will show you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61205/discussion-between-mert-and-radim-kohler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed, we need two collections, representing both directions A-B, B-A

```
public virtual IList<User> LeftFBFriends { get; set; }
public virtual IList<User> RightFBFriends { get; set; }
```

And we'd need explicit column mapping:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.LeftFBFriends)
    .Table("UserFBFriend")
    .ParentKeyColumn("LeftColumn")
    .ChildKeyColumn("RightColumn")
    .Cascade.All().Table("UserFBFriend");

HasManyToMany(x => x.RightFBFriends)
    .Table("UserFBFriend")
    .ParentKeyColumn("RightColumn")
    .ChildKeyColumn("LeftColumn")
    .Cascade.All()
    .Inverse()
```

So, this way we do correctly instruct NHibernate, which column will play parent (this ID) and which will be the child (collection ID). We have to do that for both collections